# Set values for selected dataframe cells using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two python pandas dataframes, `df1` and `df2`, and ran into a problem when I was trying to pass some values from `df2` to `df1`.

`df1` is as follow

```
   Datetime            Events
   2009-06-25          AAA;
   2009-09-29          BBB;  
   2009-10-20          CCC;
```

`df2` is as follow

```
   Datetime            History   
   2009-07-25      
   2009-09-30                
   2009-10-21
```

What I was trying to do is to append the events strings in `df1['Events']` to `df2['History']` whenever the `df2.datetime` is later than corresponding `df1.datetime`. E. g., I expect `df2` to become

```
    Datetime                       History
    2009-07-25                     AAA;
    2009-09-30                     AAA; BBB;  
    2009-10-21                     AAA; BBB; CCC;
```

I have tried the following comprehension:

```
[df2[df2['Datetime']>time['Datetime']].loc['History']+=time['Events'] for idx, time in df1.iterrows()]
```

but got error msg

> 'invalid syntax' pointing to '+=' (the same error msg when even I replaced '+=' by '='.

Can you help? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` to calculate the events up to a row on `df1` and then use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) to map the latest date in `df1` to a corresponding date in `df2`:

```
df1.Datetime = pd.to_datetime(df1.Datetime)
df2.Datetime = pd.to_datetime(df2.Datetime)

df1.Events = df1.Events.cumsum()
pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, on="Datetime").rename(columns={"Events": "History"})

#     Datetime  History
#0  2009-07-25  AAA;
#1  2009-09-30  AAA;BBB;
#2  2009-10-21  AAA;BBB;CCC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. however, in my case, df1.datetime is different from df2.datetime. df1 and df2 given above were simplified. actually there are actually more than one rows in df2 whose datetime sits in between two next rows of df1. so these two may not be merged easily.

Comment: If there are more than one row in df2 sits between two rows in df1, then they will get the same value. Isn't that what you need?

Comment: thanks for the solution and it works very well. meanwhile, is it possible to let me know what was wrong in my original solution?